# Requests_HTML in Python, why .find returns the whole page code?

Tags: python, python-requests-html

I'm trying to learn web scraping with 'resquests-html' library, and in all the tutorials, the selector html.find('.class') works well to find a CSS 'class' and return the text inside.

My example:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

s = HTMLSession()


link = 'https://prev.lifestylegarden.uk/simple-page.html'

f = s.get(link)

title = f.html.find('.title', first=True).text
print(title)
```

In my test HTML page I have:
`<h1 id="title">Welcome to our simple page project</h1>` and I want to return:

`# Welcome to our simple page project`

But at the end I am getting the whole page texts from the beginning H1 to the end, without HTML tags.

I've followed 2-3 different tutorials and different websites for test and everyone writes it that way and get string correctly from the 'class' and not the whole site.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for your great support.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the root of the issue.

I am using **Python 3.9** when this error was occurring.

I had to downgrade the version to **3.6** to make it work:

```
conda create -n envpy-3.6 python=3.6 anaconda
```

This will create a local environment called **envpy-3.6** that allowed me to create a local version of 3.6 to work on these projects.

```
activate envpy-3.6
```

This did activate the environment.